# Scaling issue with Graphics3D and Parametricplot

Tags: graphics3d, parametric-functions

There is likely a very simple solution, but I have been unable to find it.

I am using Mathematica 10.4 and wish to combine a parametric plot with a 3d vector.

Suppose I have a 3D vector drawn by

```
test1 = Graphics3D[{Arrow[{{1/10, 3/Sqrt[
      10], -(Sqrt[(5/2)]/3)}, {-3 Sqrt[2/5], 1, 0}}]}, Axes -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, u, t}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

and a parametric plot given by

```
test2 = ParametricPlot3D[{x, Sqrt[1 - x], 0.1/x}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, u, t}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

These yield the desired plots.

However, when I combine them with the code

```
Show[test1, test2]
```

I get the following image[image]

I thought using Plotrange would help, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Using `PlotRange` seems to help for me, `Show[test1, test2, PlotRange -> {{-2, 1}, {0, 1}, {-.6, 1}}]` gives me [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXXyA.png)

Comment: @Kuba - I don't really think this is a duplicate of that one, since changing the order in `Show` makes the arrow invisible.  I think it could possibly be a "Simple Mistake" close since giving `PlotRange` to `Show` fixes the problem.  But I do think there's some buggy behavior here that isn't explained by the accepted answer - just look at the insane plotrange choses by the `Show` in the OP - or compare the results of ``Charting`get3DPlotRange /@ {test1, test2, Show[test1, test2], 
  Show[test2, test1]}``

Comment: @JasonB you are right, I was too hasty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or just keep the original definitions of `test1` and `test2` and use the `PlotRange` option:

```
Show[test1, test2, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Why is `Automatic` not the default option?  I'm not sure.

Why does the default `PlotRange` result in an insane range for the 3rd coordinate?

```
Charting`get3DPlotRange@Show[test1, test2]
(* {{-1.95773, 1.06036}, {-0.0206875, 1.02083}, {-102084., 
  5.00208*10^6}} *)
```

well that seems like a bug to me...

Comment: I restarted Mathematica and the PlotRange works fine (not sure what the issue was); that was a mistake on my part. However, it is strange that the plot range didn't default to that.

Answer (score 1):

The options given to the final `Graphics3D` object are generally taken to be those specified in the first object passed to `Show`.
In This case, you didn't specify an explicit `PlotRange` argument in `test1`, and that specified in `test2` is not used, so that Mathematica chooses it automatically.

You will notice that just changing the order of the arguments of `Show`, using `Show[test2, test1]`, the blow up goes away, as in this case the `PlotRange` of the final plot is taken to be that *explicitly* specified in `test2`.

Ultimately, the blow up is due to the fact that plotting the whole of `test2` does indeed result in a plot with that scale, as you check with `Show[test2, PlotRange -> All]`.

Using your original code, without changing the order of the arguments of `Show`, you can avoid the scaling issue of the arrowhead by giving explicitly its size:

```
test1 = Graphics3D[{
    Arrowheads@0.00000005,
    Arrow[{
      {1/10, 3/Sqrt[10], -(Sqrt[(5/2)]/3)}, {-3 Sqrt[2/5], 1, 0}
      }]
    },
   Axes -> True,
   AxesLabel -> {x, u, t},
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}
   ];
test2 = ParametricPlot3D[
   {x, Sqrt[1 - x], 0.1/x}, {x, 0, 1},
   AxesLabel -> {x, u, t},
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}
   ];
Show[test1, test2]
```

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for the swift reply. All works as expected. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    test1 = Graphics3D[{ 
    Arrow[{{1/10, 3/Sqrt[10], -(Sqrt[(5/2)]/3)}, {-3 Sqrt[2/5], 1, 
       0}}]}];

test2 = ParametricPlot3D[{x, Sqrt[1 - x], 0.1/x}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-0.5, 1}},
    AxesLabel -> {x, u, t}];

Show[{test2, test1}]
```

yielding this:

[image]